# Knockout kendo ui date time picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

I am using Knockout kendo ui date time picker in one application and am reusing same application for other project here i want to change the date time format which should effect all the screens at once with out changing the existing code in asp.net mvc5

Thank You In Advance

Comment: Please show us some code that you have written so far to implement this

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `knockout-kendo` bindings, then you can set options globally for any of the bindings like:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.kendoDatePicker.options = {
    format: "yyyy/MM/dd"
};
```

Alternatively, you could set the culture for all widgets using `kendo.culture` as described here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview